# spring security pre auth using java config

Tags: spring-security

I am trying to setup pre auth security in spring using an external service. The login entry point redirects to an external page which upon successful login puts the authentication information in a cookie. After that the external app redirects back to my app and my `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` is invoked properly and I am able to return a principal value which then I am expecting to be passed to my userdetailservice where i can create the proper user object but it ends up throwing an error before that. Here is the code

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider preAuthenticatedProvider;

    @Autowired
    private CspProperties cspProperties;

    public SecurityConfig() {
        super();

        userDetailsService = new CspUserDetailService();
        UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> wrapper = 
                new UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken>(userDetailsService);

        preAuthenticatedProvider = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
        preAuthenticatedProvider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(wrapper);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(preAuthenticatedProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        CspAuthenticationFilter cspFilter = new CspAuthenticationFilter();
        cspFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());

        //entry point
        LoginUrlWithReturnUrlEntryPoint entryPoint = new LoginUrlWithReturnUrlEntryPoint(cspProperties.getNoCookieURL());

        http
            .addFilter(cspFilter)
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/secure").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
            .httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint);
    }
}
```

this is the error I am getting

```
2014-06-28 12:30:46.522 DEBUG 13752 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] secure.CspAuthenticationFilter           : Checking secure context token: null
2014-06-28 12:30:46.524 DEBUG 13752 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] secure.CspAuthenticationFilter           : preAuthenticatedPrincipal = 6045656|aeb4b387f41c1557cfb2604
881840b96|W|40|CDTTut,CompXL|xxxxx|PROD|201406290157, trying to authenticate
2014-06-28 12:30:46.524 DEBUG 13752 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] secure.CspAuthenticationFilter           : Cleared security context due to exception

org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderNotFoundException: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preau
th.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doAuthenticate(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.jav
a:121)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:91)
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score -2, accepted):

turned out this configuration is correct the problem was in the pre auth filter which wasnt returning null in some cases where it should have.

Comment: Could you extend Your answer? What was the problem? I'm facing identical and cannot find a reason